# How is File(".").getAbsolutePath() resolved under the hood?

Tags: java, file, io, operating-system

I was wondering:

1. What happens after I ask for an absolute path of the current file in Java?

   ```
   String s = File(".").getAbsolutePath();
   ```
2. How does an interpreter find the path to the current file in the filesystem? Is there some OS system call for this?
3. Does it return the path of a jar? Or sometimes it can return the path where the file was before compilation?

Comment: A simple implementation could be to just keep asking for the parent of the current file until there are no more parents. The list of names you can then be joined by and separated by the path delimiter (`/` for everything else and `\ ` for windows), and that gives you the absolute path

Comment: We ask OS for parent? And the result is the path to compiled jar?

Comment: Note that `"."` is the current *directory* not the current file, so question 3 is moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every process has a "current directory".

From within the process, the path `.` refers to this current directory.

The actual path denoted by the current directory is (can be) a parameter to the system call that created the process (see `ProcessBuilder` for instance), or it can be inherited from the process that creates your process.

The current directory is an attribute of the process, and is completely unrelated to the location of the jar file.  The two paths *may* match by coincidence.

There is no requirement that the `.` path refer to a writable location, or indeed any location in a filesystem.  There may not even be a file system.  That is, the path `.` is not required to exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. 2. For `.` and `..` there is the current working directory, `System.getProperty("user.dir")`, which may be different at point of excecution, like in the IDE and stand-alone. `.` has nothing to do with the location of the jar,
      but in which directory `java` is started.

   So a path "a/./b/../c" will become "a/c". As there are disk operating systems with `...` it just might be that a native call is made. Also Windows might want to replace POSIX `/` with `\`.
2. String to File will always be done at run time. However *where* the application is started, the current working directory or `.` - that depends, varies in fact.
   Never at compile time, even a `static File f = new File("./readme.txt");` creates an object when the class is loaded the first time.

Here `File` is a class for a phyiscal disk file.

A more general class, `Path`, is superior in that it can also have its path run inside a zip file, or any feasible URI that provides a file system view.

So I will use `Path` for further explanation. There is a worthwile utilities class [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) with Path operations, allowing you to copy some file from inside a zip archive to some location on hard disk.

[`Path.absoluteFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toAbsolutePath()) is the Path version of getting the absolute path (depending on the file system view).

[`Path toRealPath​(LinkOption... options)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toRealPath(java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) with optional options does disk operating native calls (for a File) when *symbolic links* are wanted to be replaced with the actual physical paths. `/a/b.lnk/c` could actually be `/a/d/e/c`. This call is important should you want to detect if a path unwantedly escapes some restricted directory.

Comment: _"Here `File` is a class for a phyiscal disk file"_. However, the Javadoc for `java.io.File` says it is "An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames" without reference to files on disk.

Comment: @JimGarrison That means that the path does not need to physically exist. It does not need to have a file handle, inode or such.